# i am working on groups members and fences

Tags: php

```
 public function data(Request $request)
    {
        $result = $this->_model->get_teams($this->_user->user_id);
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $team = array_only((array)$result[0], ['id', 'name', 'type', 'created_by', 'dp_id']);
            $team['status'] = $result[0]->team_status;
            $team['created_at'] = $result[0]->team_created_at;//group detail ends
            $team['members'] = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                if ($team['id'] != $row->id) {
                    $teams[] = $team;
                    $team = array_only((array)$row, ['id', 'name', 'created_by']);
                    $team['status'] = $row->team_status;
                    $team['created_at'] = $row->team_created_at;
                    $team['members'] = array_only((array)$row, ['id', 'name', 'created_by', 'username', 'email', 'mobile', 'designation', 'member_id', 'role']);
                    $team['members']['territories'] = $this->_model->members_territory(array($row->member_id));
                    $team['members']['fences'] = $this->_model->members_fences(array($row->member_id));
                } else {
                    $team['members'] = array_only((array)$row, ['id', 'name', 'created_by', 'dp_id', 'username', 'email', 'mobile', 'designation', 'member_id', 'role']);
                    $team['members']['territories'] = $this->_model->members_territory(array($row->member_id));
                    $team['members']['fences'] = $this->_model->members_fences(array($row->member_id));
                }
            }
            $teams[] = $team;
            $team['members'][] = array_except((array)$row, ['id', 'name', 'type', 'created_by', 'team_status', 'team_created_at', 'dp_id']);
            $this->_response->status = "OK";
            $this->_response->message = "success";
            $this->_response->result = $teams;
        } else {
            $this->_response->status = "ZERO_RESULTS";
            $this->_response->message = "No team registered against this user";
        }
        return response()->json($this->_response);
    }
```

i want to fetch all of my members from group here i am doing little mistake 
and i cant find it please make same help,me  to find where i am doing actually mistake

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHPCodeChecker](https://phpcodechecker.com), it helps me all the time :)

Comment: What does this have to do with his problem (which he hasn't even explained clearly)?

Comment: @Barmar It gave an error when I tried to run the code, probably because the whole code is needed.

Comment: i am not getting all members with terrirtories

Comment: i want teritories and fences in all members ,,and fetch all members record